# CSS, jquery, ajax, or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, jquery-ui

I want to make this kind of window using CSS, JQUERY, AJAX, OR JAVASCRIPT
I don't care as long as i get following results

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.PropertyGrid

Can you please tell me which library I can use to have this
look and feel?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a problem with using the ExtJS / Sencha library you are referencing? That would be the way to get the exact result you are looking for ;)

Comment: You will most likely need all four of them.

Comment: @user431276: *"ExtJS is not free"* Well, you didn't mention anything about free/non-free in your question. But ExtJS is free if you are willing to also make *your* work available for free: http://www.sencha.com/products/license.php But if you need a free library without that requirement, I list several in my answer.

Comment: @.user , people might have felt its too generic question

Comment: @user , what are you using on the server side right now , Microsoft , javas ,php ??/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I dare say that specific page is using the [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/) library (as that's the API docs page for it)... ;-) It's achieving what you see through a mix of CSS and JavaScript.

You can achieve something *similar* using CSS and just about any library, whether ExtJS or [jQuery](http://jquery.com) + [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) + [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) (or even without a library, if you want to work unnecessarily hard).

Comment: @Crowder Trying to develop such a complex web-app without using a JS library would be just plain stupid (the only justification for it being ignorance). To want to work hard is something different.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Agreed. I actually meant to put "unnecessarily hard" but appear to have missed a bit out. :-)

Comment: @user431276: *"ExtJS is not free"* I never said it was, although if you're willing to release your application under the GPL v3, ExtJS is indeed free: http://www.sencha.com/products/license.php  All of the other libraries I listed are free as well, and most of them don't have that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI might be a good starting point and includes all of the technologies you mentioned.

More importantly you should learn about them and understand what they are doing in detail though...

And, uh, ExtJS is a good framework too.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS has a decent learning curve but its not too bad.  You need to know minimal HTML/CSS but will have to be pretty proficient with JavaScript.